# Passing DataTable to Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, datatable, procedure

I want to pass DataTable to Oracle procedure which creates a Temporary table.
Even My procedure needs changes to accept datatable as parameter.
I want datatable in place of existing_table.

Below is the Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure temptable
is
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from existing_table';
End;
```

How do I work through this. Please help!

Comment: does this have anything to do with C#? If so what is the context?

Comment: The DataTable is to be passed from C#

Comment: i would suggest searching for a start tutorial on how to build application that use a database

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure temptable (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    l_cnt number;
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    -- if TEMP_TABLE already exists, drop it
  7    select count(*)
  8      into l_cnt
  9      from user_tables
 10      where table_name = 'TEMP_TABLE';
 11
 12    if l_cnt > 0 then
 13       execute immediate 'drop table temp_table';
 14    end if;
 15
 16    -- create a new TEMP_TABLE
 17    l_str := 'create global temporary table temp_table on commit preserve rows ' ||
 18             'as select * from ' || par_table_name;
 19    execute immediate (l_str);
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec temptable('dept');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from temp_table;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

**However**, in Oracle, you don't really create/drop tables *dynamically* - you create them once and use them many times. For a global temporary table, you'd create it once and populate as necessary in different sessions.

There might be requirements as yours (i.e. to use the same table name for different data sources), so - if that's your case, see if the above code helps.